# Difference between two table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Table - `OriginalTable` & `NewTable` and I'm using `MySQL`. Both tables have one only column `OrderId` . I want to find the difference between these two tables. Below are the three use cases -

**Case I** -  OriginalTable has extra OrderId.

**Case II** - NewTable has extra OrderId.

**Case III** - Both table has identical record.

I have used Select with Left Join/Right Join. I'm ok even if i need to run one query for each use case. I haven't solved the third use case yet. Not sure if there is something readily available to find difference in MySQL.

Comment: Yes..Select with Left Join/Right Join... i'm ok even if i need to run one query for each use case. I haven't solved the third use case yet.

Comment: Why not put that into the question?

Comment: @Pankaj Take a look at my solution and try these queries and get back to me whether that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Case 1 

Run Query->

SELECT * FROM OriginalTable WHERE OriginalTable.OrderID not IN ( SELECT NewTable.OrderID FROM NewTable)

Case 2

Run Query->

SELECT * FROM NewTable WHERE NewTable.OrderID not IN ( SELECT NewTable.OrderID FROM NewTable)

Case 3

Run Query->

SELECT * FROM OriginalTable WHERE OriginalTable.OrderID IN ( SELECT NewTable.OrderID FROM NewTable)
```

You can also run join such as this to only get identical order id in both tables

```
Case 3    
SELECT * FROM OriginalTable JOIN NewTable ON OriginalTable.OrderID = NewTable.OrderID
```

AND If you want to find out which records are different in both of the tables then you can run:

```
SELECT * FROM OriginalTable JOIN NewTable ON OriginalTable.OrderID = NewTable.OrderID WHERE OriginalTable.OrderID IS NOT IN (SELECT NewTable.OrderID FROM NewTable) OR WHERE OriginalTable.OrderID IS NOT IN (SELECT OriginalTable.OrderID FROM OriginalTable)
```